# Where is "places" in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, places

I moved from 10.04 to 12.04 tonight and I'm lost.  I can't find partitions of drives.  I installed the classicmenu indicator but that doesn't have a "places" option on it.  Where is everything?

I just want to see all my drives/ partitions etc in one place whether they're mounted or not.  I'm sure there is something like that here but I have no idea where.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Click on the Home folder, your Places are on the Nautilus sidebar or in the Go menu in Nautilus.

Comment: It seems that only mounted partitions/ devices are there.  How do I get to the unmounted ones and choose to mount them?

Comment: use gnome-disks to configure mount point

Comment: Thanks but that went over my head a little.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Nautilus shows all partitions in the drive in its sidebar, if you want to mount them simply click on them. An eject button will show next to the partition, click it to unmount it.

Answer (score 2):

In **Nautilus** we can define *View --> Sidebar --> Places"* to see available directories and drives. Available unmounted partitions will be mounted and their content will be displayed on selecting them with the mouse.

[image]